# How to close a browser window from Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a Google Apps Script for Google spreadsheets which opens a secondary browser window  (for authentication to an external system).

After the authentication we get a redirect to the webapp part of the script (doGet).

How do I close the browser window from Google Apps Script (so that the user can continue in the spreadsheet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the design to solve the issue:

1) I do no longer use a webapp in GAS to wait for some authentications codes. We instead poll (via UrlFetch) our server from the GAS side until the authentication has completed.

2) I now let the authentication window close itself

```
window.open("","_self","").close();
```

The code might look tricky, but it works with current browsers. ( The more natural looking window.close() doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

Have you developed your interface using `UiApp` or `HtmlService`?

If it's `HtmlService`, have you tried [`google.script.host.close()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#close%28%29)? I'm not sure if it's going to work though. If you test it, please give feedback here. -- **edit** from feedback on comments, it seems that does not work for standalone scripts, just if it's embeeded on sidebars or dialogs.

If it's `UiApp`, then it's not possible, [see issue 474](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=474&can=1&q=close%20window&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner).

Comment: Meaning you're using HtmlService and attempted to run this on your client-side code, right? Is so, thanks for the feedback. Also, you probably should open this as a feature request on [apps script tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p>Link established.</p><script>function test() { alert('Done'); google.script.host.close();};</script><button onclick='test()'>Close</button>");