# Google Apps Macro to Open And Close Chrome Tabs

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm newbie on Google apps programming. I need help regarding opening and closing Chrome tab using Google sheet macro with 40 sec interval loop

Here is my code to open a tab

```js
function openTab() {
var selection=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();

var html = "<script>window.open('" + selection + "');google.script.host.close();</script>";

var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Open Tab');
}
```

I just don't know how to close the current chrome tab and do the looping with 40 secs.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @KevinStevenAsistin, was the answer below able to fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

For time-driven intervals, use [`Installable Triggers`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead. Note that interval (in minutes) is only limited to the options below. You can have daily, weekly, and also other intervals on the setup. Feel free to check it out.

[image: interval]

As for the closing of tab, see related questions and its answers below if it works on you.

#### Similar questions:

- [How to automatically close window created by Google Script Content Service/HTML Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565438/how-to-automatically-close-window-created-by-google-script-content-service-html)
- [How to close a browser window from Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287066/how-to-close-a-browser-window-from-google-apps-script)